# AWS ECS Deployment Stuck with two deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS service with Status PRIMARY, desired count set to 1, whose deployment has been "In progress" for more than an hour and it has a 2nd deployment with Status ACTIVE, desired count set to 0,  whose deployment seems stuck in "Completed".

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue before? The minimum healthy percent is 0, so I don't understand what's happening here.

This is an issue for me because I'm using ansible (`command: aws ecs wait services-stable --cluster {{ ecs_cluster_id }} --services {{ service }}`) to check if the service is stable after deployment and due to the 2 deployments it does not succeed.

EDIT: I noticed a task in a STOPPED state in the "Tasks Stopped" tab and in the "Events" tab a message more than one hour ago "(service x, taskSet ecs-svc/9969948609626318494) has begun draining connections on 1 tasks."

Then suddenly after a bit more than one hour "service x (deployment ecs-svc/9969948609626318494) deployment completed." and the task in STOPPED state is gone and now the ansible command succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be solved.
Let me explain what I was doing and what I did to solve it.

Before:

- I was stopping my sandbox ECS containers running in EC2 instances by setting the desired capacity of the ASGs to 0 -> by doing only that, ECS was constantly trying to start tasks during the night, although there were no EC2 instances running
- In the morning I was setting the desired capacity of the ASGs back to 1, but I was also deploying the ECS services again (I really need this step because I usually push some code changes off-hours) -> this was causing the issue with the two ECS deployments

Fix:

- set the ECS services desired tasks to 0 + set the desired capacity of the ASGs to 0
- In the morning, setting the desired capacity of the ASGs back to 1 and deploy the ECS services again as before